# Webmin -> Virtualmin -- How to access FTP?

Tags: ftp, webmin, virtualmin

I'm trying to access FTP using WinSCP. I made an FTP user for an specific virtual server. I tried many combinations of session details but none of them work. I also can't find a clear guide/documentation what details are necessary.

Edit:
What details should work by default? like

```
File protocol: FTP
Encryption: TLS/SSL implicit encryption
Host name: example.com
Port number: 21
User name: x.example.com
Password: xxxxxx
```

I'm curious what i'm doing wrong and wether or not this is just a firewall related issue.

Edit2:
When i feel like i enter all the details properly i get this error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Connection failed.
```

I did ufw allow ftp

Comment: I'm gonna guess there is no good FTP solution build in Webmin/Virtualmin and go for an external solution

Comment: After several days of failing to get a server set up with webmin/virtualmin, I'm beginning to conculded there is no good solution of any sort built into it. Everything seems to be much harder to do with it than to just do by hand from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get sftp access.

Installed openssh-server -> `apt-get install openssh-server`
Install webmin module -> proFTPd
Add user in webmin -> system -> users and groups  -- setting up:

```
username
password
new group/ primary group === username
```

Would still like to know if there is a better way. Sorry for bad spelling but im really tired.